# iconos en una lista aspx

Tags: c#, dropdownlist, aspx

Me gustaría enseñar una lista de idiomas con un icono de la bandera al lado. Estoy intentando usar el ListBox y la propiedad ImageUrl de los ListItem pero no muestra nada. Estoy mirando cualquier ayuda por internet pero creo que todo eso no es para la pagina .aspx que estoy usando. Supongo que estoy mirando ejemplos webforms o algo así. Soy nuevo en esto.

y el compilador me dice que no puedo poner objetos dentro del objeto ListItem.
Estoy probando con <asp:Dropdownlist y <asp:ListBox, pero no hay manera.
Necesito enseñar una banderita, el nombre del idioma y luego usar la selección desde código con onselecteditemchanged o como se llame.

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server"> 
 <asp:ListItem 
   ImageUrl="~/imagenes/english.png">English</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

ImageUrl o src , ninguna funciona

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: No puedes colocar imágenes en un ListBox ni en un Dropdownlist

Comment: Para hacer eso tienes que usar otro tipo de control, alguno de Telerik, Devexpress, o algun componente de jquery  por ejemplo Select2 https://select2.org/dropdown

Aqui hay un ejemplo de lo que quieres hacer con utilizando Jquery https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/33b051/binding-image-indropdownlist-in-asp-dotnet/